# Loop through excel folder and copy range from each file into active worksheet on active workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, range

I have posted a similar question but managed to figure out how to do what I need - almost!

I have the below code which works great EXCEPT the information is being copied to the active workbook into row 21. I don't know how to change this. If I change this section it goes to the top of the sheet but I would like to place the information starting in row A2 and then each row after that:

Works to insert at row 21:

```
'Set the destrange
Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A2" & rnum)
```

Works to insert at top of sheet:

```
'Set the destrange
Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & rnum)
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\jlinney\OneDrive - Distell\Desktop\Personal\NOMAD\Global Mobility\Excel From"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wbk = Workbooks("Excel to.xlsm")
    
    Set BaseWks = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A2:H2")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                       'With sourceRange
                            'BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    'Resize(.rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                        'End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A2" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply try

```
rnum = 2 ' Start row
BaseWks.Range("A" & rnum)
```

The term `"A" & rnum` will do a *string concatenation*. When you set rnum to 1, this will result in `"A1"`. If you set it to 2, this will give you `"A2"` and the data will be copied into the second row.

When you write `BaseWks.Range("A2" & rnum)`, the string `A2` and the content of `rnum` will be concatenated, so in your case that gives `A21`.

Comment: An even clearer way of doing the same thing, but keeping rnum with the same meaning and start value, would be to refer to the output cell using:
BaseWks.Cells(rnum+1, 1)

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try this now. I have added in an extra bit of code to delete all the blank rows in the meantime which seems a little mad but it works for me for the moment :-)

Comment: Just updated with this and it worked perfectly. Thanks very much